# Custom License Plates without specific characters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I have a license plate that has 3 capital letters followed by 2 digits but it can't have both Z and 6 in it at the same time.

My guess for a possible logic is: All possible license plates - (License plates with any number of Z's and 6's simultaneously)

All possible license plates would be: $26^3 \cdot 10^2$

But I can't seem to figure out the subtraction part in my logic.

Comment: Do you know the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: I know it faintly, but this is not a stats course question and I would prefer a more mathematical solution.

Comment: @RobertShore: quote "I can't seem to figure out the subtraction part in my logic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $26^3 \cdot 10^2$ total plates.

You have to subtract off all plates with at least one Z and one $6$.  There are $6 \cdot 26^2 \cdot 10$ of those.

But this double-counts plates that are "bad" for two reasons.  So you have to add back plates with one Z and two $6$s ($3 \cdot 26^2$) and also add back plates with two Zs and one $6$ ($6 \cdot 26 \cdot 10$).

Now you've added back too many.  Subtract back plates with two Zs and two $6$s ($3 \cdot 26$).  Also subtract back plates with three Zs and one $6$ ($20$).

Finally, you must add plates with three Zs and two $6$s ($1$).

So the answer is $26^3 \cdot 10^2  -6 \cdot 26^2 \cdot 10 + (3 \cdot 26^2+6 \cdot 26 \cdot 10) - (3 \cdot 26+20) +1$.

Comment: Sorry about that, 3 capital letters followed by 2 digits. Just edited my question.

Comment: Same logic.  I've modified the answer to give the right numbers for the new question.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of additions and subtractions. Generally for these kinds of questions which is a better approach? Should I just add the possible options or subtract from the whole as you did above?

Comment: Whatever works, but the principle of inclusion and exclusion is pretty general.